# How to prevent vector from expanding when assigned values give NumberFormatException error?

Tags: java, vector, command, try-catch

I insert values into my command line... integers that are input will be inserted into my vector, and strings such as "dog" etc will be caught by NumberFormatException. However, in my code I receive an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException... I understand why but how can I prevent this?

I want my code to print out that the vector accepts the integers, but it rejects the strings, and to continue reading my input in the command line.

**Additional problem I am facing... how do I get my error causing string to print?? My code gives me "For input string: "dog"" when I just want "dog"**

```
    int i;
    int result;

    Vector numbers = new Vector();
    for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
        try {
            result = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        System.out.println("Converter method says integer OK - " + result);
            numbers.add(i, result);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("Catch block says the argument" + e.getMessage() + "is ignored because" + e.getMessage());

        }
    }
```

Example input: 11 22 33 dog 44 cat 55 66

**

My output:

Converter method says integer OK - 11

Converter method says integer OK - 22

Converter method says integer OK - 33

Catch block says the argumentFor input string: "cat"is ignored becauseFor input string: "cat"

Converter method says integer OK - 44

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4 > 3

```
at java.base/java.util.Vector.insertElementAt(Vector.java:619)

at java.base/java.util.Vector.add(Vector.java:857)

at exceptionalcommandline.ExceptionalCommandLine.main(ExceptionalCommandLine.java:16)
```

**

Expected Output:

Converter method says integer OK - 11

Converter method says integer OK - 22

Converter method says integer OK - 33

Catch block says the argument "cat" is ignored because "cat"

Converter method says integer OK - 44

Catch block says the argument "dog" is ignored because "dog"

Converter method says integer OK - 55

Converter method says integer OK - 66

Comment: Change `numbers.add(i, result);` to `numbers.add(result);` and ask yourself what you tried to do there. You want to add to the end of the list. However when there is a non-number, you were trying to insert at one place **past** the end of the list. `numbers.add(result);` always append to the end of the list.

Comment: "*Slams head against the wall*" thank you for that! Do you also have a cure to my "e.get.message()" situation? I appreciate your help!

Comment: Just use args[i] instead of e.getMessage()

Comment: Change `e.getMessage()` to `args[i]` ?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you get an exception i value will still increase. So there will be a gap between available index and the i value you want to add after the exception. So change your code to:

```
for (i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    try {
        result = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        System.out.println("Converter method says integer OK - " + result);
        numbers.add(result);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Catch block says the argument" + e.getMessage() + "is ignored because" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```